# Change language preference in TeXworks?

Tags: miktex, texworks

I have installed the MikTeX 64 bit version for Windows, but the interface of the TeXworks editor uses some foreign language. During installation, it did not ask me my language preference. Is there an option to get back to English, I cant find any option regarding the same.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to TeX.SX. The language of what, exactly? The MikTeX  settings and package manager, the TeXworks editor, or something else?

Comment: I mean the options , the toolbar , on the editor i can type and get a pdf generated in english. But when it comes to using the options on the toolbar, I cannot understand.

Comment: In the current version (2.9.5823) of MikTeX there are no translations available for TeXWorks, only English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the interface language of the TeXworks editor, go to Edit --> Preferences --> General.

- The Edit menu is the second from the left, and the preferences is the bottom entry.
- The General tab is the first tab, and the language is chosen in the drop down-menu at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @EricNunes No problem. Note that while TeXworks is part of MikTeX, they are not the same thing. I edited your question slightly to reflect this, hope that's OK (if not, please revert my change).