# How to change the language from German to English in MiKTeX?

Tags: miktex

Since I have a German Windows system, it seemed that my MiKTeX installed German interface automatically. Anyone knows how to get rid of this and have an English MiKTeX installed?

Comment: Why the LaTeX 3 tag? `:)` Just a typo?

Comment: What german interface? Everything in my miktex is in english. Well with the exception of texworks. You can change the language there in the options.

Comment: Do you mean the TeXworks editor? In that case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125465/change-language-preference-in-texworks/125469#125469

Comment: Yea, so everything in the program is in German including those commands like "open",help , etc