# Language options

Tags: languages

I just installed the MikTeX and want to change the language for editing to Spanish, but it does not give me the choice. I can´t (it does not give the choice neither) use these options:
http://docs.miktex.org/manual/hyphenation.html
or
[Change language preference in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125465/change-language-preference-in-texworks)

What can I do?

Comment: you question is unclear. What do you mean `I can't (it does not give the choice neither)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your LaTeX installation provides essentially command line tools (latex, pdflatex, ...) to process text files containing markup. You may need to install language support to handle text in non-English (for hyphenation and naming of parts of the text like the bibliography), check the `babel` package. To be able to type native text (not bletcherous typearounds like `\'a` instead of plain `á`), you need to use an appropriate input encoding, today most commonly `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble.

External tools (like the editor used to input the text and perhaps others) aren't part of your LaTeX installation, and will have to be configured separately. You mention MikTeX, so you are presumably using Windows, and I'm sorry that I can't help there.